# Hanoi Tower Algorithm using recursion, while show the step count

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

We all know the python code to solve Hanoi Tower problem looks like:

```
def hanoi(n, a, b, c):
    if n == 1:
        print a, '-->', c
        return
    hanoi(n-1, a, c, b)
    print a, '-->', c
    hanoi(n-1, b, a, c)

hanoi(4, 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

My question is where to add `print('stepCount ={}'.format(stepCount))` to show the stepCount for each step.

****Update & Clarification*****
while the output of the code above shows:

```
A > C
A > B
C > B
A > C
B > A
B > C
A > C
```

I am wondering if print statement can be added to the code to change the output to:

```
stepCount: 1
A > C
stepCount: 2
A > B
stepCount: 3
C > B
stepCount: 4
A > C
stepCount: 5
B > A
stepCount: 6
B > C
stepCount: 7
A > C
```

Comment: The steps are printed in the exact order they're executed, what do you mean by "step-count" ?

Comment: @alfasin, hi, I have updated the question. please take a look

Comment: Lazy solution: just have a function with a global count variable that prints and updates the count whenever it gets called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@emplatetypedef described a solution like the following:

```
def hanoi(n, a, b, c, count):
    if n > 0:
        count = hanoi(n-1, a, c, b, count)
        count += 1
        print('stepCount: {}'.format(count))
        print('{} --> {}'.format(a, c))
        count = hanoi(n-1, b, a, c, count)
    return count

hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C', 0)
```

It can also be implement with a global variable (yes I know ugh...):

```
def hanoi(n, a, b, c):
    global stepCount
    if n > 0:
        hanoi(n-1, a, c, b)
        stepCount += 1
        print('stepCount: {}'.format(stepCount))
        print('{} --> {}'.format(a, c))
        hanoi(n-1, b, a, c)


stepCount = 0
hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

**OUTPUT** (of both code snippets)

```
stepCount: 1
A --> C
stepCount: 2
A --> B
stepCount: 3
C --> B
stepCount: 4
A --> C
stepCount: 5
B --> A
stepCount: 6
B --> C
stepCount: 7
A --> C
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can update this to print out a step count. You can pass down through the recursion an extra parameter keeping track of the step number at the start of the recursive call, then have the recursion return the final step number once the call has ended. Some things to think about:

1. What initial value would you use?
2. How would you capture the return values from the individual recursive calls?
3. What would you do with the values that you capture?